# UnidentifiedImageError PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001B2A6DF7650>

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library, face-recognition

I have a python flask app and calls a function from another .py file. The following is that file:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import numpy as np
import io


class processimage:
    def create_parent_folder(drive_service, parent_folder_name):
        # Check if the parent folder exists
        query = f"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='{parent_folder_name}'"
        results = drive_service.files().list(q=query).execute().get("files", [])

        if results:
            # Parent folder already exists, return its ID
            parent_folder_id = results[0]["id"]
        else:
            # Parent folder does not exist, create it
            parent_folder_metadata = {
                "name": parent_folder_name,
                "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
            }
            parent_folder = (
                drive_service.files()
                .create(body=parent_folder_metadata, fields="id")
                .execute()
            )
            parent_folder_id = parent_folder["id"]

        return parent_folder_id

    def create_folder(drive_service, folder_name, parent_folder=None):
        folder_metadata = {
            "name": folder_name,
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
        }

        if parent_folder:
            # If parent_folder is provided, set it as the parent
            folder_metadata["parents"] = [parent_folder]

        folder = (
            drive_service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields="id").execute()
        )

        # Replace with the ID of the file you want to share
        permission_metadata = {
            "type": "anyone",
            "role": "reader",
        }

        # Add the permission to the folder
        drive_service.permissions().create(
            fileId=folder["id"], body=permission_metadata
        ).execute()

        return folder["id"]


    def list_files_in_folder(drive_service, source_folder_id):
        # List files in the source folder
        results = (
            drive_service.files()
            .list(
                q=f"'{source_folder_id}' in parents and trashed=false",
                fields="files(id, name)",
            )
            .execute()
        )
        files = results.get("files", [])
        return files

    def find_face_encodings(image_path):
        image_path = processimage.preprocess_image(image_path)
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image_path)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_path, face_locations)

        if not face_encodings:
            return None
        else:
            return face_encodings

    def preprocess_image(image):
        image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image_rgb = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
        return image_rgb

    def list_face_encoding(files):
        known_faces = []
        print("filess", files)
        for file in files:
            image_2_url = "https:....." + str(file["id"])
            response = requests.get(image_2_url)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                image_data = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
                image_p = np.array(image_data)
                image_p = cv2.cvtColor(
                    image_p, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR
                )  # Convert to BGR format
                image_2 = processimage.find_face_encodings(image_p)
                print("response done")
            else:
                print("########", response.status_code)
                print("###############", response.text)

            i = 0
            while image_2 is None:
                image_p = cv2.rotate(image_p, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
                image_2 = processimage.find_face_encodings(image_p)
                i += 1
                print(f"Changing orientation.")
                if i == 4:
                    print("No face found")
                    break
            known_faces.append(image_2)
        return known_faces

    def face_to_be_checked(image_1):
        image_1 = cv2.imread(image_1)

        image_1 = processimage.find_face_encodings(image_1)
        # print("image_1 at package",image_1)
        n = 0
        while image_1 is None:
            image = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
            image_1 = processimage.find_face_encodings(image)
            print("No face found in the reference image.", n)
            n += 1  # photo is not not detected in the input
            if n == 4:
                print("no face found,check image")
                break
        return image_1
```

The problem I am facing is in the list_face_encodings function which is UnidentifiedImageError

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001FDE90AA750>

Specifically the ' image_data = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))'.

I have tried most of the solutions suggested for similar problems I found in stackoverflow and github but still its not working. The code has been working till now and suddenly it started showing this error. I have updated pillow to the latest version still no use.

Comment: I would do something like this: r = requests.get('https://www.bimbaylola.com/media/catalog/product/1/8/182BAC104_T2200_P_T_XX_1.jpg', stream=True)
aux_im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))

Comment: Don't spam the `opencv` tag if it has nothing to do with **OpenCV**. Do make sure your example is minimal - do we need to see your code for creating parent directories? Try printing the first 40 bytes of `response.content` with `print(response.content[:40])`

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Opencv tag was put because the main flask app program makes use of it and I gave the full code for context. The thing is the code again started working again without doing anything. I dont understand why

Comment: @toyotaSupra - the only difference with my code and the solution is the stream=True part right. Currently it works both ways either putting stream = True or not putting it. But yesterday I tried this and didnt work.
Also the response content is -b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x06\x04\x05\x06\x05\x04\x06\x06\x05\x06\x07\x07\x06\x08\n'

Comment: The response content looks like a perfectly normal JPEG to me, so I have no idea why PIL wouldn't recognise it. Try reading it with **OpenCV** like this `BGR = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(response.content),dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)`

Comment: Yeah thats the thing. But now it suddenly started working again as before.-@MarkSetchell